# Switch User, Logout, Lock Screen--All Broken

Tags: 12.10, lock-screen, logout, switch-user

At various times, which I can't pin down exactly, my 12.10 with Unity fails to lock the screen after timeout, fails to log me out when I click Log Out, fails to switch users when I command it, fails to shutdown or restart.

Sometimes I can't log into either of the two profiles that are set up on the machine and have to reboot it. Sometimes the reboot doesn't fix this and I have to shut the machine down and restart it to be able to log in.

Another thing I noticed that may or may not be related is that often, when I try to click on something in the panel on the top right that has a drop-down menu, the menu won't come down until I click on a menu on the left, drop a menu down over there, then go BACK to the right hand side and then the drop-downs will work.

This has been going on in one form or another since 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

Today I found a post that seemed to help matters. As I said I have two profiles on this computer. The second one is used for the kids and has (had) no password. Apparently having an account without a password can cause these types of problems. I have put a password on that account and everything seems to be a lot better. Not sure if all is completely well yet because some of the issues I have been having are intermittent.

I will report back. In the meantime, if anyone else is having these kinds of problems and you have a password-less account set up, try giving it a pw.